# How do I find the exact solidity compiler version used by truffle?

Tags: truffle, etherscan

I'm trying to verify a contract I have compiled and deployed onto the network using [Etherscan](http://etherscan.io). The contract was compiled using truffle. How do I work out exactly which version of the solidity compiler to select on Etherscan?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to find a hacky way of doing this. Note - I was looking for more than just the version of solc. I was looking for the actual build of the compiler that solc was using (ie the commit used, night build number etc) so that I could could select it on [EtherScan](https://etherscan.io/).

I have truffle installed globally so I ran `which truffle` which allowed me to eventually find (following symlinks) where truffle was stored on my mac: `/Users/username/.nvm/versions/node/v7.7.3/lib/node_modules`

From here it was easy to locate where the solc installation used by truffle is also stored. Relative to the previous path it would be in `./truffle/node_modules/solc`

At this point - if you just want the version of the solc package you can look in `package.json`

If you want to go further and find the specific compiler version (like me) then take a look in `wrapper.js` and look for the `var version` variable declaration. It turns out this is a function which will return the compiler version name being used. Simply `console.log(version());` on the next line and when you next run `truffle test` or `truffle compile` the solidity compiler build will be output into your console. For me this looked like:

```
var version = soljson.cwrap('version', 'string', []);
console.log(version());
```

Remember to return the wrapper.js file to its original state after you have got the info you need.

**Note:** This is a very hacky way of doing it. There's probably a better way but it was the first method I stumbled on. Even then - it didn't even help me get the contract verified on Etherscan, anyway.

Comment: The other methods suggested below are much more straightforward, I suggest editing this answer to reflect that there are much easier ways.

Answer (score 15):

I'm running Truffle `3.4.11` and running just: `truffle version` gives me the Solidity version as well:

```
truffle version                                                                                                                                                           
Truffle v3.4.11 (core: 3.4.11)
Solidity v0.4.15 (solc-js)
```

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to get compiler version with truffle is to find it in your project directory `./build/contracts/YourContractName.json` near the bottom of the file.
It looks like,

```
 "compiler": {
    "name": "solc",
    "version": "0.4.18+commit.9cf6e910.Emscripten.clang"
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can look at the file `./node_modules/solc/package.json` and see something like `"solc@^x.y.z"` where `x.y.z` is the version number that is being used.

Answer (score 1):

If you have npm installed with the -g flag, you can do this (omit the -g if you have it installed locally)

`$ npm -g ls | grep solc
  └─┬ solc@0.4.18`

That should be your version.