# Solidity Browser and Truffle giving different bytecodes

Tags: solidity, truffle, remix

I am compiling in solidity browser and then compiling the same exact code in truffle.

The code is the following:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;
contract double{function d(int256 a)constant returns(int256){return a*2;}}
```

The resulting bytecodes are different from each other.

```
Truffle:
0x60606040523415600e57600080fd5b5b60978061001d6000396000f300606060405263ffffffff7c01000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006000350416636482e6268114603c575b600080fd5b3415604657600080fd5b604f6004356061565b60405190815260200160405180910390f35b600281025b9190505600a165627a7a723058203747098ed60838a4e4a3a8ba05db5e7f3eeb60237761809e1f89f6007b52938e0029


Solidity Browser:
6060604052341561000f57600080fd5b5b60ab8061001e6000396000f30060606040526000357c0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000900463ffffffff1680636482e62614603d575b600080fd5b3415604757600080fd5b605b60048080359060200190919050506071565b6040518082815260200191505060405180910390f35b60006002820290505b9190505600a165627a7a72305820e77f3602d7e14b8ffd5ef32976d823a77ab5c91be0a1cad7a188ff3bdba9d4ea0029
```

Is there anything else I need to do in truffle so I can make it compile exactly the say solidity browser does?

Comment: are you using same compiler?

Comment: I am using truffle as it comes and using solidity browser as it comes... The compliver version is the same in both

pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

Answer (score 2):

using  `^0.4.11` means your contract will be compiled using by the compiler 0.4.11 or a newer version (current version is 0.4.15).
so I think truffle and solidity browser are using different compiler. you need to check which version is used. 
Truffle : [How do I find the exact solidity compiler version used by truffle?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/18133/how-do-i-find-the-exact-solidity-compiler-version-used-by-truffle)

 Remix : [image]

Comment: Unfortunately matching up the compiler versions still did not produce the same result in the bytecode.

Comment: have you enabled the optimization in remix?